# Aptana PHP Code Formatter - Doesn't work?

Tags: php, aptana, formatter

Aptana's code formatter is fairly straight-forward. But it does not seem to work?

In some cases it formats nicely, but in others, it sticks the code flat against the left.

I could paste examples, but overall its just horrible.

Is this a known fact or does there exist upgrades of any sort needed for PHP formatting?

Comment: Aptana's format chokes on mixed PHP and HTML - I would guess that's where you are having trouble. I wish I could tell you it'll be fixed in an update, but I tend to doubt it. Netbeans is good, though you may find there are things you miss from Aptana if you switch. You could also try Eclipse proper with the Aptana extension.

Answer (score 0):

Well change IDE, i have never used aptana so i cant vouch for it. Netbeans is feature rich if you dont mind wasting a few cpu cycles. Otherwise there are the fabled text editors like notepad++ (use under wine for nix) or gedit for nix or vim.

I personally think there are better ide's then aptana. Sorry i couldn't be muck more help than that.

Good Luck

Comment: No prob. I just jumped into Ubuntu and am looking to replace dreamweaver.

Comment: good work, drop windows. I did. then i installed a vm because the amount of software i had for windows outweighed anything i could do in nix. boo hoo. but the vm only is fired like once a week. :) netbeans in my choice, otherwise i still use notepad++ under wine.